# B module can't depend A module's dependency that declare provided scope in IDEA multi-module maven project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Structure:

```
ROOT
  |- AModule
        |- pom.xml
  |- BModule
        |- pom.xml
  |- pom.xml(parent pom)
```

`pom.xml` in **AModule**:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>30.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>   <!--servlet-api declare "provided"-->
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

`pom.xml` in **BModule**(depend AModule):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>AModule</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I want to use `servlet-api` in **BModule**(maybe more modules: CModule, DModule...), but it is not included in **BModule**, can **BModule** use **dependency** that declare `<scope>provided</scope>` in **AModule**?
[image]

Comment: Why not add servlet-api as a dependency to BModule? What's the bid deal?

Answer (score 1):

No, `provided` dependencies are not transitive.

Furthermore, you should not directly use the dependencies of your dependencies. Better declare them explicitly.